# JQuery Validation disable validation if form is for updates

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form with fields that need to be unique in the database like say Username, when creating a new user the validation works by using the remote method to check if the username exists, this works fine. the challenge is I use the same form for updates, an ajax request gets the user details and populates them in the same form allowing the updates to be done, but with validation, the username input finds an error so cannot update, How can I disable the remote method only during the update, or can I get better solution?

Comment: Extend or delete the `remote` option as needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While create/update maintain a input field as shown follows with `value=''`

of course `value=""` at the time of "create" and some value(id of record being updated) at the time of "update" operation, that you have to set as per operation being performed.

```
<input type="hidden"  name="update_id" value='' id="update_id">
```

Now at the time of validation

```
username: {
            required: true,
            remote  : {
                        type: "POST",
                        async: false,
                        url: yourUrlHere,
                        data: {
                                id: function() 
                                {
                                  return $("#update_id").val();
                                }
                              }

                       }

        }
```

here we are sending update_id no matter operation is Create/Update i.e 
"" while create and some value(id of record being updated) at the time of Update.

You can then have username checking logic on a page `url: yourUrlHere,` like if  `'id'= '' then check from all records for duplicate username or if  'id'= 'someVal'  then check from all records for duplicate username except 'id'= 'someVal'`

Comment: this implies I send both update_id and username to the URL:yourUrlHere, which is not possible with remote, or do you mean I check if update_id is empty before doing the remote verification

Comment: Yes you need to send username and update_id both at the time of validation using remote.and check at server URL:yourUrlHere if username exist .

Comment: used this query in url:usernamecheck.php and it worked  SELECT * FROM tbl_users where username in ($username) and idusers not in ($idusers);